# SQL Calculate Median of change

Tags: sql

I have a data with ID, start_end, budget.
I can calculate the change in budget for each ID from the start (0) to the end(1).
However, I need to get the MEDIAN for the change.

In my data, the result should be Median=0 (the middle one).

Can you please help me?

Thank you,

Harry

```
drop table mytable;

create table mytable (
ID int,
start_end varchar(255),
budget varchar(255)
);

insert into mytable (ID,start_end, budget)
values('a','0','500'),('a','1','1200'),('b','0','100'),('b','1','100'),('c','0','500000'),('c','1','3000');

SELECT a.ID, a.budget as start_budget, b.budget as end_budget, (b.budget-a.budget) as change
FROM mytable as a join mytable as b
on a.id=b.id
where a.start_end=0 and b.start_end=1;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide desired results.  Also, how do YOU define the "median"?  You only have two rows for each id, so "median" doesn't seem particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest standard way to calculate the median is to use `percentile_cont()` or `percentile_disc()`:

```
SELECT t.*,
       percentile_cont(0.5) over (partition by id order by budget) as median_budget
FROM mytable t;
```

Most databases support `percentile_cont()`.  You can refer to the documentation for your database.

Comment: I must miss something

`SELECT percentile_cont(0.5) over (partition by id order by (b.budget-a.budget)) as median_budget

FROM mytable as a join mytable as b

on a.id=b.id

where a.start_end=0 and b.start_end=1;`

Comment: @harry . . . A self join seems superfluous.  But as I say in a comment, you should provide sample data *and* desired results and explain what you mean by "median".

Comment: Oh, I did provide data and the desired result should be 0 as median.